# When I send a JS object to a Node.js server and ask for the same object back, the server sends back a modified object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I have a web page that establishes communication with a `node.js` server. I am sending it objects and having it return the same object that it received. However, the object that is returned is different - all of its methods are gone.

Here's code that shows what I'm doing. I send an event with an object:

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(event) {
    socket.emit('modificarCodigo', event);
});
```

And I return it like this:

```
socket.on('modificarCodigo', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.grupo).emit('actualizarCodigo', data);
});
```

How can I get `node.js` to return the object that I send to it intact instead of modifying it? I have a guess that the behavior I'm seeing now is by design - if that's true, how can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot serialize functions into JSON. If you really need to send functions then you'll have to `.toString()` them, send them, and then `eval` or `new Function` them back into existence, but that is a risky proposition... Why do you need to send methods?

**Edit:** The OP added a comment that what he is trying to do is pass and Ace editor `Range` object over the wire...  I think you would be better off sending just the data required to build a new Range object. So just send startRow, startCol, endRow, and endCol and then on the other end of the wire you can do new Range(data.startRow, data.startCol, data.endRow, data.endCol).

As a side note, the proper serialization of an object can be handled (if your js engine supports JSON.stringify/parse) using a [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON#toJSON%28%29_method) method. Here is an example:

```
function Dude(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Dude.prototype = {
    speak: function() { alert('My name is ' + this.name); },
    toJSON: function() {
        return {
            type: 'Dude',
            props: { name: this.name, age: this.age }
        };
    }
};

http.get('http://getadude.com', function(json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);

    if(type === 'Dude') data = new Dude(data.props.name, data.props.age);
})
```

Comment: I am using the ace editor, and I need to remove a segment, so I need to send the segment that is to be erased. This segment is represented by a Range object, and I has to have the `isEmpty()` method so that ace's `remove` method works

Comment: I think you would be better off sending just the data required to build a new Range object. So just send startRow, startCol, endRow, and endCol and then on the other end of the wire you can do `new Range(data.startRow, data.startCol, data.endRow, data.endCol)`

Comment: Yes I see, but I have create another question because the constructor of the range object is not working. here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452869/ace-js-range-constructor-raising-an-exception)

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your object as JSON before sending it and decode it after. It should work.

Comment: I misspoke it's not an attribute what is lost, it's a method.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your really wanting RPC, for which node has an awesome library called dnode.  https://github.com/substack/dnode