# When I try to create a Range object in ace.js, an "Illegal Constructor" error is thrown

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to create a Range object for the `ace.js` editor in my code, but it's not working. It is failing in a way I can't figure out. In [the Ace documentation](http://ace.ajax.org/api/range.html), this constructor is:

```
new Range(Number startRow,
          Number startColumn,
          Number endRow,
          Number endColumn)
```

But when I try this in my code:

```
new Range(0, 0, 0, 1)
```

It raises an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor` error. What is causing this behavior, and why doesn't it match the documentation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Range` is a native type is most browsers that you cannot instantiate. I'm not really familiar with Ace, but I'm guessing that they use some sort of namespacing so that you will do something like `new Ace.Range()`.

**Edit:** It looks like they are using CommonJS, so you can import the method and alias it however you like:

```
var Range = require('ace/range').Range,
    mine = new Range(0,0,10,0);
```

Comment: that was it, just that I'm not using CommonJS, so the solution was `var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range`
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does not work for me: in browser console I get error: `TypeError: ace.require is not a function` - any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `require('ace/range').Range` with `ace.require('ace/range').Range`

Comment: Does not work for me: in browser console I get error: `TypeError: ace.require is not a function` - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

`import { Range } from "ace-builds"`

Answer (score 1):

This solution `var Range = ace.acequire('ace/range').Range;` works for me!!!

Full code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387989/630169