# Is it possible to serialize an Ace Session object?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'd like to serialize and store Ace Session objects, so I can open a "File" and restore everything, value, selection, cursor position, mode, etc.

I've tried `JSON.stringify(session)` and it throws a circular error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reposted on the Ace mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ace-discuss/6o7pKfOBAJQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the simplest version would be

```
var session = editor.session
state = {}
state.value = session.getValue();
state.selection = session.selection.toJSON()
state.options = session.getOptions()
state.mode = session.getMode().$id
state.folds = session.getAllFolds().map(function(fold) {
    return {
        start       : fold.start,
        end         : fold.end,
        placeholder : fold.placeholder
    };
});
state.scrollTop = session.getScrollTop()
state.scrollLeft = session.getScrollLeft()

JSON.stringify(state)
```

and to restore

```
session.setValue(state.value)
session.selection.fromJSON(state.selection)
session.setOptions(state.options)
session.setMode(state.mode)
try {
    state.folds.forEach(function(fold){
        session.addFold(fold.placeholder, 
            Range.fromPoints(fold.start, fold.end));
    });
} catch(e) {}
session.setScrollTop(state.scrollTop)
session.setScrollTop(state.scrollLeft)
```

this doesn't cover restoring undomanager which is doable but a little trickier. you can try to bump this issue https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1452

Comment: thanks for the response, will give it a try soon and report back :)

Comment: head over to http://js-play.com in devtools, run `root.ace._session.selection.toJSON()` - No toJSON function, and `JSON.stringfy` is circular. Which version has `toJSON`?

Comment: the latest https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/ace.js#L7694-L7706

Comment: ah awesome, will give that a try

Comment: Thanks for this - the docs really let us down for things like this. I was almost tempted to switch to codemirror until I found this answer.

Comment: Thanks for such ace API investigation: saved tons of time for others!

Comment: I get error on fold restore: `TypeError: Range.fromPoints is not a function`. Shows Range as a function. Any ideas? Something similar to the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10452869/630169 - however solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution combined from 3 sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404474/630169
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260919/630169
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311510/630169

Moved session serialization code to a separate module:

## editor-session.js:

```
var ace = require('brace');
var Range = ace.acequire('ace/range').Range;

var filterHistory = function(deltas) {
    return deltas.filter(function (d) {
        return d.group != "fold";
    });
};

/** @param {AceAjax.Editor} editor */
function sessionToJson(editor)
{
    return {
        content: editor.getSession().getValue(),
        selection: editor.getSelection().toJSON(),
        options: editor.getOptions(),
        mode: editor.session.getMode().$id,
        scrollTop: editor.session.getScrollTop(),
        scrollLeft: editor.session.getScrollLeft(),
        history: {
            undo: editor.session.getUndoManager().$undoStack.map(filterHistory),
            redo: editor.session.getUndoManager().$undoStack.map(filterHistory)
        },
        folds: editor.session.getAllFolds().map(function(fold) {
            return {
                start       : fold.start,
                end         : fold.end,
                placeholder : fold.placeholder
            };
        })
    }
}

/** @param {AceAjax.Editor} editor */
function jsonToSession(editor, state)
{
    editor.session.setValue(state.content);
    editor.selection.fromJSON(state.selection);
    editor.session.setOptions(state.options);
    editor.session.setMode(state.mode);
    editor.session.setScrollTop(state.scrollTop);
    editor.session.setScrollLeft(state.scrollLeft);
    editor.session.$undoManager.$undoStack = state.history.undo;
    editor.session.$undoManager.$redoStack = state.history.redo;
    try {
        state.folds.forEach(function(fold) {
            editor.session.addFold(fold.placeholder, Range.fromPoints(fold.start, fold.end));
        });
    } catch(e) {console.log('Fold exception: ' + e)}
}

module.exports.sessionToJson = sessionToJson;
module.exports.jsonToSession = jsonToSession;
```

## Browser side JS: processed by browserify

```
var ace = require('brace');
var state = require('./editor-session');
var editor = ace.edit('web-editor');

...

function saveEditorSession() {
    localStorage.setItem('editorSession', JSON.stringify(state.sessionToJson(editor)));
}

editor.getSession().on("change", function () {
    textarea.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
    // Save editor session to localStorage
    saveEditorSession();
    // Send editor content to backend
    ajax.saveContent(textarea.value, function (response) { });
});

editor.getSession().selection.on('changeSelection', saveEditorSession);
editor.getSession().selection.on('changeCursor', saveEditorSession);
editor.getSession().on('changeFold', saveEditorSession);
editor.getSession().on('changeScrollLeft', saveEditorSession);
editor.getSession().on('changeScrollTop', saveEditorSession);
```

Comment: suggestion: use `editorOptions : editor.getOptions(),
            options       : editor.getSession().getOptions()` and `editor.session.setOptions(state.options);
        editor.setOptions(state.editorOptions);`  - it's possible the api has changed since you posted this, i was getting errors with your original code.