# Ace editor - save/send session on server via POST

Tags: javascript, php, variables, session, ace-editor

I write online webpage editor and I would like save current view/work on server, for restore in future. I also want do multiple tabs.

I know, that is `editor.getSession()` and `editor.setSession()`.

JS:

```
var editor = ace.edit("description");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow");
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true
});
```

Now I try save session via jQuery `$.data()` to element:

```
$('#tab1').data('sesi',editor.getSession()); //save session
editor.setSession($('#tab2').data('sesi')); //restore other session
```

But this code not working. When I try `console.log(editor.session);` I see a lot of code in console.

I tried send `session` to server via POST data, but in network console I see only code from editor and nothing more...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "aaaaa.php",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    data: "session="+ editor.session
});
```

How to save session to variable or to server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to save session to server you need to convert it to plain object which can be passed to json.Stringify. `session="+ editor.session` in your example simply calls session.toString which is same as session.getValue

```
var filterHistory = function(deltas){ 
    return deltas.filter(function (d) {
        return d.group != "fold";
    });
}

sessionToJSON = function(session) {
    return {
        selection: session.selection.toJSON(),
        value: session.getValue(),
        history: {
            undo: session.$undoManager.$undoStack.map(filterHistory),
            redo: session.$undoManager.$redoStack.map(filterHistory)
        },
        scrollTop: session.getScrollTop(),
        scrollLeft: session.getScrollLeft(),
        options: session.getOptions()
    }
}

sessionFromJSON = function(data) {
    var session = require("ace/ace").createEditSession(data.value);
    session.$undoManager.$doc = session; // workaround for a bug in ace
    session.setOptions(data.options);
    session.$undoManager.$undoStack = data.history.undo;
    session.$undoManager.$redoStack = data.history.redo;
    session.selection.fromJSON(data.selection);
    session.setScrollTop(data.scrollTop);
    session.setScrollLeft(data.scrollLeft);
    return session;
};
```

now to get state of the session do

```
var session = editor.session
var sessionData = sessionToJSON(session)
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "aaaaa.php",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    data: JSON.stringify(sessionData)
});
```

and to restore it from the server

```
var session = sessionFromJSON(JSON.parse(ajaxResponse))
editor.setSession(session)
```

Comment: Are 2 little bugs: `data = sessionToJSON(session)` change to `data = sessionToJSON(editor.session)`, and `data: JSON.stringify(editor.session)` change to `data: JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: @a user, You can't use only `session` because this is undefined variable. `editor.session` is corectly.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. The code assumes you can obtain `session` somehow be that from `editor.session` or some other function passing a session.

Comment: For other people, in my script I must change `var session = require("ace/ace").createEditSession(data.value);` to `var session = ace.require("ace/ace").createEditSession(data.value);`

Comment: if you are using noconflict version the global `ace` is same as `ace.require("ace/ace")`

Comment: Ok. I set only `ace.createEditSess....` and is good. But I have problem with `Ctrl+Z` after change session in editor. I have error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undoChanges' of undefined`. I looked anywhere, but I don't know where is source this problem.

Comment: That is a bug in ace, i've updated my answer with a workaround for it

Comment: Seems now `Selection` object foes not have `toJSON()` method: https://ace.c9.io/#api=selection&nav=api - any way to save/restore it? Use `JSON.stringify`? However seems Selection does not have any properties - only methods.

Comment: Thanks for such ace API investigation: saved tons of time for others!